# How to format a number 123456 to 123,456 in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, numbers, currency

I am getting a number (e.g., 450000) as a result from a mongodb query. I want to format the number with a thousands separator (like currency) as 450,000.

> Number: 1593324
>
> Expected Output: 1,593,324

How can I achieve this in mongodb?

Comment: You don't. mongodb queries are not a programming language. Why can't you write a function in the code you're using to access the database?

Comment: You really shouldn't try. Part of the NoSQL philosophy in general is to get rid of the API bloat inherrent to many SQL databases and just focus on the tasks at hand. Trivial things such as formatting are better handled in client code. MongoDB does not really offer **any** "tranformation" routines outside of the aggregation framework or mapReduce. The aggregation framework does not have the operators to do this. Using mapReduce is certainly overkill for such a task. Format your numbers in your client code. It's where you should have been doing it all along, even if something else let you do it.

Comment: @PrashanthChandra: My aim to format the number using query so that on front end number formation operation can be eliminated.

Answer (score 2):

you can't achieve this in mongodb because this is not programming language.

But You can use:

variableName.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

and then call to store this string in database

**example:**

var test = 1593324;

test.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

**and then output i m getting :
1,593,324**

Comment: We can achieve the same using in built javascript toLocaleString() function.

For example, a = 1000;

a.toLocaleString() will return 1,000

Even we can use angular js currency filter to achieve this.